# Symfony 3.0 nested entities not saving

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

So I have an Experiment Entity which has many RNASeq entities. However, when I try to save an Experiment with an RNASeq entry (via the `newAction`), only the Experiment portion saves.

My controller is as follows:

```
    <?php
    // src/AppBundle/Controller/ExperimentController.php
    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use AppBundle\Entity\Experiment;
    use AppBundle\Entity\RNASeq;
    use AppBundle\Form\Type\ExperimentType;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

    // TODO: deleteAction should be implemented. 

    class ExperimentController extends Controller {
        /**
         * @Route("/experiment/index", name="experiment_index")
         */
        public function indexAction() {
            // Grab all experiments from database and hand them to template. 
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Experiment');
            $experiments = $repository->findAll();
            return $this->render('experiment/index.html.twig',['experiments' => $experiments]);
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/experiment/new", name="experiment_new")
         */
        public function newAction(Request $request) {
            $experiment = new Experiment();

            $form = $this->createForm(ExperimentType::class, $experiment);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            // On submission.
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $em->persist($experiment);
                // For each nested object. 
                foreach($experiment->getRNASeqs() as $rnaseq) {
                    $em->persist($rnaseq);
                }
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirectToRoute('experiment_index');
            }

            return $this->render('experiment/form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/experiment/show/{id}", name="experiment_show")
         * TODO: Not sure if nessesary (wasn't in last system).
         */
        public function showAction($id) {
            return $this->render('experiment/show.html.twig');
        }

        /**
         * @Route("/experiment/edit/{id}", name="experiment_edit")
         */
        public function editAction(Request $request, $id) {
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Experiment');
            $experiment = $repository->find($id);

            $form = $this->createForm(ExperimentType::class, $experiment);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            return $this->render('experiment/form.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }

}
  ?>
```

I've attempted to follow the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). However, it doesn't specifically go over a One-to-Many example, and I fear this is possibly where I've messed up.

For the sake of brevity my Entity classes and the rest of my code can be found [here](https://github.com/lutrasdebtra/bioinf_poem/tree/master/src/AppBundle/Entity).

Edit:

I've noticed that during a creation event, the `insert into` events don't seem to have the correct relationship attributes:

```
    INSERT INTO experiment (title, exp_type, sample_nums) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: fe, 2: RNASeq, 3: 'a:1:{i:0;i:68767;}' }

    INSERT INTO rnaseq (quality, ribodepleted, final_quality, sample_num, protocol_used, step1, step1result, service_provider, platform, data_files, pipeline, pipeline_parameters, result_files, experiment_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Parameters: { 1: fds, 2: 0, 3: fes, 4: 7876, 5: esf, 6: 0, 7: fsd, 8: fs, 9: fs, 10: fsd, 11: sdf, 12: fds, 13: fsd, 14: null }
```

`Experiment` appears to be missing an update to its `rnaSeqs` attribute, and `RNASeq` has a `null` parameter for `experiment_id`.

Comment: Do you even get in the foreach (foreach($experiment->getRNASeqs() as $rnaseq)). Try to output the number of children to be sure the relation is filled : $experiment->getRNASeqs()->count()

Comment: It outputs `int(1)`, which I assume means I'm getting the children? (I used a single child). I've confirmed this by going into the loop and printing a variable (Quality): `string(2) "ef"`.

Comment: Just a question : Which version of symfony are you using ? 3.0 ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (Updated the title and corrected the tag, thanks for the spot).

Comment: It seems you forgot the `sampleNums` property in your `experimentType`. According to your entity annotations, this can't be null.

Comment: Added in `sampleNums`. However, problem persists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very common issue.  You need to take care of cross referencing your objects.  Doctrine does not do this automatically though many people initially seem to think it will.

```
class Experiment {
  public function addRNASeq($seq) {
    $this->seqs[] = $seq;
    $seq->setExperiment($this);  // This is what you are missing
```

And add the attribute cascade=all to your Experiment::seqs property.  Then you won't need to explicitly persist the seq entities.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I'll keep than in mind for future objects. Thanks so much!