# Symfony2 - how to automatically persist new entities from CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm on Symfony 2.8. In my `Work` entity I've got:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\WorkClaim", mappedBy="claimedWork", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $claims;

/**
 * @param WorkClaim $claim
 */
public function addClaim(WorkClaim $claim)
{
    $claim->setClaimedWork($this);
    $this->claims->add($claim);
}

/**
 * @param WorkClaim $claim
 */
public function removeClaim(WorkClaim $claim) { /* to be done */ }
```

(and getter/setter and of course `$this->claims = new ArrayCollection();` in the Constructor)

In my `WorkClaim` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Work", inversedBy="claims")
 */
private $claimedWork;
```

(and getter/setter)

My `WorkType` class has this in the form builder:

```
->add('claims', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type' => WorkClaimType::class,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
))
```

`WorkClaimType` has just some typical fields (`EntityType` to choose country, two `DateType` fields and `NumberType`).

No matter what I do, the `addClaim()` is called, but the new `WorkClaim` entities are added with NULL `claimed_work_id`. What did I miss?

Do I really have to persist every `WorkClaim` separately in `Work` controller on `createAction()`? And if so, how to correctly iterate through them? Trying to call `getClaims()` on form data gives me no records.

Comment: You need to cross link your entities at the object level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34197674/symfony-3-0-nested-entities-not-saving/34204093#34204093

Comment: @Cerad: isn't that handled already? I've got $claim->setClaimedWork($this); inside addClaim()...

Comment: That isn't handled already - you're just adding PHP objects to other objects at that point.  You must either explicitly persist them in Doctrine, or set the Doctrine entities to cascade persist (so you don't have to do it explicitly).

Comment: OK, but I've got both, cascade={"persist"} in Work entity and call to SetClaimedWork in AddClaim(). I just don't see what I miss here.

Comment: So your claims are actually getting persisted?  It's just that the work id is null in the database?  Strange.  Make sure you don't have any files lurking under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: And verify the WorkClaim::setClaimedWork($work) is properly implemented.

Comment: OK, I really don't know what to say. It works now. And to be honest, I don't remember changing anything. Suddenly the id is not null in the DB now...