# Easyadmin One-to-Many: not displaying form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine, symfony2-easyadmin

With Easyadmin, Symfony3 and Doctrine I'm trying to display an embedded form for an Article to add Urls to itself.

However, the article form currently **does not show** the UrlType form, but instead text boxes which - what it seems - expect Ids of the Urls I would like to add.

[image]

I found that the following configuration should be working (according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007362/symfony-easyadmin-one-to-many-form)):

```
       form:
            fields:
                [...]
                - { property: 'urls', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'MyVendor\MyBundle\Form\UrlType', by_reference: false }  }
```

Article:

```
class Article
{
    [..]  

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Url", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $urls;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->urls = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add url
     *
     * @param Url $url
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function addUrl(Url $url)
    {
        $url->setArticle($this);

        $this->urls[] = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove url
     *
     * @param Url $url
     */
    public function removeUrl(Url $url)
    {
        $this->urls->removeElement($url);
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUrls()
    {
        return $this->urls;
    }
}
```

Url:

```
class Url
{
   [..]  

    /**
     * @var Article
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="urls")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $article;


    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param Article $article
     *
     * @return Url
     */
    public function setArticle(Article $article = null)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }
}
```

UrlType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('address', TextType::class);
    $builder->add('description', TextType::class);
}
```

I have checked, double checked and tried so many things in the code and searched google as well as stackoverflow.

How can I display fields to add new URLs to the Article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the friendly folks at [EasyAdmin](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1651) this issue has been resolved. It turns out that despite of using the fully qualified namespace to UrlType in YAML config, the type is overwritten with the [Symfony UrlType](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/url.html).

**Solution**: Rename `MyVendor\MyBundle\Form\UrlType` to for example `MyVendor\MyBundle\Form\UrlEntityType`

This looks like a bug in either Symfony or EasyAdmin.