# Easy admin : collection of forms

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I am trying to build a simple backend application based on EasyAdmin. The ORM is Doctrine.

I have set up 3 entities :
* Entity A has a unidirectional many-to-many relation to entity B
* Entity B has a one-to-one relation to entity C
* Entity C has some basic properties

In EasyAdmin I have set up the Entity A and Entity C. The purpose is to add/edit Entity B while adding/editing entity A. II found the following which is exactly what I want. [symfony easyadmin one to many form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007362/symfony-easyadmin-one-to-many-form).

But when I want to add an Entity B while adding Entity A, it creates a form with the appropriate fields but the form has its own save button. Which seems to conflict with the main save button. [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lvsq.jpg)

Is there a working example of what I want to achieve or some documentation on how to do it ?

Regards

Christophe Absil

Comment: Now everything is ok but I still have this extra save button. Is there a way to not display it ? The main save button is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good idea would be to override the 'new' and 'edit' templates. You have [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/edit-new-configuration.html) the official documentation to help you.

While rendering the form, you will be able to hide/add labels & buttons; in order to hide a form element, just add:

```
 {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

A final step would be to override EasyAdmin's AdminController in order to persist the second entity; [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/book/complex-dynamic-backends.html) is the official page.

Good luck!