# Need advice about Symfony4 easy_admin related entity form creation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

Im pretty new in symfony.
Now i have new project an i need a advice, what technlogy to choose.
I spotted, that symfony4 almost all demos installs easy_admin and it looks like good choice.
But now for few days im struggling with some issues and lack of documentation, information.
So i want to know - is my idea possible in easy admin in easy way (not writing almost everythong custom) and i just cannot find proper documentation or i need to chose another solution (any suggestions?)

So i have database with one table, which have more than 10 related tables.
When i create new base entity i want to add all related entities in one window.
And exactly add, not chose from already prepared, because i need to done job in one form, not move between more than 10 forms to make one record (customer doesnt care about relations).
Maye i can create base record and on edit add all related entities.
And related entities can be almost every type - OneToOne OnetoMany ManytoMany.

So i really need advice, how this job can be done, because i tried multiple ways in relations and i can only choose from already inserted records, but cannot add new. 
All related entities have multiple input fields - it needs full form generated.

Comment: I want 2 know - is this possible, because none of documentation reveals this.
So dunno what code exactly you want?

Answer (score 1):

Created sample project, awailable on github [Web Forest](https://github.com/Chepainais/web-forest)
Goal is make clear manual, how to do things not fully explained in official EasyAdmin manual or demo.

Project goal nr.1: achieve all related entities insert from one Forest insert and/or edit form. All types - OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany.
Explain for novices, what exactly we do wrong and how to do thing more clearly.

Please feel free - comment, commit changes, add more features.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom form class and reference it in yaml config file through `entry_type` option. For example, imagine that User entity has related entity UserSettings (with fields `code` and `value`) and you want to edit these settings right in the User edit form:

Form class:

```
class UserSettingsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => UserSettings::class
        ]);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('code')
            ->add('value');
    }
}
```

YAML config:

```
easy_admin:
    entities:
        User:
            class: App\Entity\User
            edit:
                fields:
                    - ...
                    - { property: 'settings', type: 'collection', type_options: { entry_type: 'App\Form\EasyAdmin\UserSettingsType' , ... }}
```

I've stumbled upon this solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40007362/symfony-easyadmin-one-to-many-form)